# Custom variables in stripe using PHP

Tags: php, html, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make a payment system where I want the payment amount to show up on the payment screen. This is what i have tried so far but the `$amount` doesnt get shown:

```
<?php
use Stripe\Stripe;
require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); // Include the Stripe PHP library

// Set your Stripe API key
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('');

global $amount;

// Handle the payment request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Get the payment token and other details from the form submission
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $amount = 100;
    $description = "Mads Langer Fest";

    try {
        // Create a charge using the Stripe API
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            'amount' => $amount,
            'currency' => 'dkk',
            'description' => $description,
            'source' => $token
        ));

        // Payment successful - display a thank you message to the user
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
        // Payment failed - display an error message to the user
        echo 'Your payment could not be processed. Please try again later. Error message: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}


// Output the payment form to the user
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='amount' placeholder='Amount'>
    <script src='https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js' class='stripe-button'
        data-key=''
        data-amount='" . $amount*100 . "' 
        data-name=''
        data-description='Widget'
        data-image='https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png'
        data-currency='dkk'
        data-locale='auto'></script>
</form>";
?>
```

This is the result im getting without amount info:

[image]

This is what I want with amount info:

[image]

Comment: It's unclear how to the two snippets of code fit together. Is `$amount` definitely defined when you try to use it in the data-attribute? Where are you expecting that to come from, when generating the form? Have you checked the generated HTML source code to see what's actually in that data-attribute?

Comment: ofc my bad, i updated the post so its one snippet now. When i look at the data-attribute in html it doesnt show up. Is it because the data-attribute gets set after the html gets created?

Comment: i just tested it, and the problem was indeed that $amount does not get defined before creating the html.

Comment: Thanks. In your code, `$amount` is only defined when the form is posted back, not when it's being loaded.

Comment: Is there a way to work around this problem or should i just define the `$amount` beforehand?

Comment: If you need it beforehand, then define it outside the `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {` block.

Comment: P.S. `global $amount;` makes no sense here, because you don't appear to be within a function at that point. I suggest reviewing your understanding of that keyword and of [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in general.

Comment: Please also note it's a very-very old version of Stripe, so it might be hard to find documentation or support for it. Look at some of the newer ways to integrate Stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?lang=php